# How to convert mdadm raid1 to single driver and keep the data?

Tags: software-raid, mdadm, diskmanagement

I have a raid1 created by mdadm in the root partition on `/dev/nvme1n1p2` and `/dev/nvme0n1p2`, efi boot partition is on /dev/nvme1n1p1. Then I followed some commands to remove one of the disks and formatted it to mount in /media.

```
mdadm /dev/md0 --fail /dev/nvme0n1p2 --remove /dev/nvme0n1p2 
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/nvme0n1p2
```

Current mdstat

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md0p1
/dev/md0p1:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Tue Sep 27 15:52:16 2022
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 438311936 (418.01 GiB 448.83 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 438313984 (418.01 GiB 448.83 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Thu Sep 29 02:14:09 2022
             State : active, degraded
    Active Devices : 1
   Working Devices : 1
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : ubuntu-server:0
              UUID : 765832c2:a4431240:90b2a7d7:69430147
            Events : 1679

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0     259        5        0      active sync   /dev/nvme1n1p2
       -       0        0        1      removed
```

How to delete md0 and keep the root partition data of /dev/nvme1n1p2?
I think I just need to reboot into rescue mode then

```
umount /dev/md0p1
mdadm --stop /dev/md0p1
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/nvme1n1p2
```

and edit the fstab, change root partion from /dev/md0p1 to /dev/nvme1n1p2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly no, you cant. Because partition table has no record about your filesystem. Check this with fdisk or gparted.

https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Partition_Types

https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/A_guide_to_mdadm#Array_internals_and_how_it_affects_mdadm

> Also superblock Version 1.2 is stored 4K from the start of the device. These superblocks also define a "data offset". This is the gap between the start of the device, and the start of the data. This means that v1.2 must always have at least 4K per device, although it's normally several megabytes. This space can be used for all sorts of things, typically the write-intent bitmap, the bad blocks log, and a buffer space when reshaping an array.

So filesystem blocks starts somewhere from the begining of partition not where it should be. If you use lvm on top of mdadm it even worse.

You may try testdisk to check if it can see your filesystem and modify partition table for you or find start of filesystem manually and update partition table manually or copy data, create fs and copy data back or just stay with it as is - its not harm you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm missing some basic concepts. Actually, when I ask this question both disks have data, I ended up copying the two partition to /dev/nvme0n1p1, then create efi and root partition on  /dev/nvme1n1 and copying it back.

Comment: Successfully converted 8TB drive with one `mdadm` RAID1 GPT partition `/dev/sda1` formatted with XFS to "regular" drive/partition like so: 1. `mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda1`, 2. change file system type with `fdisk` to `20` (Linux filesystem), 3. fix partition table with `testdisk`. Thanks much for the `testdisk` hint!